# Regarding REST Path Conflict

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am creating two methods(GET) in a REST service in which the URL is for the first method is of the form

> **/a/b/{parameter}?start=1 &
>   end=100 & name="some value"**

and for the second method it is

> **/a/b/{parameter}**

When i run the code it gives a conflict.
Can anyone please suggest me how these can be configured for the methods and also to make the query paramters OPTIONAL?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have default values for start & end?

Comment: No there is no default value for start and end.

Comment: REST is a **resource**-based approach. Do you mean that you have nearly the same URI pattern for 2 different kinds of resources? That would be weird... The first step is defining what are you resources. Could you tell us more about them?

Comment: We have two methods (GET) which have got nearly same URL.Only the query Parameters are different.When I use the path as same(@Path("/a/b/{parameter}")) it throws a conflict exception.However the query parameters are different for the two methods.Can you please suggest how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
@GET
@Path("/a/b/{parameter}")
public Response get(@PathParam("parameter") String parameter, @QueryParam("start") Integer start, @QueryParam("end") Integer end, @QueryParam("name") String name) {
    // switch here according to the values received. All are optional and non-sent are nulls here
}
```

If in the future you will have default values you can add them inline like this (for the name query param for example):

```
@DefaultValue("some-name") @QueryParam("name") String name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have done the implementation s suggested however there is another method whose path is (@Path("/a/b/{parameter}")) same which conflict and throws exception.Can you please tell me what else needs to be changed?

Comment: The method I suggested is a union of both. When the user does not send the query params they will be null and you can execute the code accordingly as stated in the comment in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Cant we have two different methods for this?we need to implement two separate methods.Is there a way to do this?Also we have different response for both the methods.

Comment: All you mentioned can be done with 1 method. Switch in the method and delegate to a sub-method according to the case. The response is not an issue too as the Response object can hold any kind on HTTP response.